# Fixing the first row as sortable title in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, sorting

I know this is super easy, I just couldn't find it.

I'd like the first row in an excel document to be the "title" field. I want that:

1. Whenever I scroll down, this row will remain fixed
2. I can sort and filter according to the different columns.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: 1002 views and not a single upvote. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To fix the first row select it and then select "Freeze Panes" from the "View" ribbon.

To get sorting and filtering select the first row and then "Filter" from the "Data" ribbon.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the first row ;

1. First click Window → Split
2. Move splitter bar wherever you want to split
3. Click Window → Freeze panes (if you want to freeze it)

Answer (score 2):

A good option might be to convert the data area to a table - with any cell in the data selected, go to Insert Ribbon > Table, make sure the checkbox for "my data has headers" is ticked and OK.

This will add filters automatically, make formatting easier, give you the option for total row and other things to make life easy (once you get used to using Tables).

When you scroll, the column labels (A, B, C etc) are replaced with the header row titles. Only downside is that you can't get at the filter dropdowns without going to the top of the table (this is improved in 2010 by showing them in the column headers as well - [read more about tables in Excel 2010 here](http://wp.me/p2I5L-3V))